# Backbone - remove last model in Collection, but only by filter

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

```
this.keysCollection.pop();
```

Removing the last one is pretty simple, but what I'd ideally like to do is this (pseudo solution):

```
this.keysCollection.pop({ type: 'foo' });
```

And for it to remove the last matching model from the Collection. Possible?

EDIT:

Went with this -

```
const models = this.where({ type: 'foo' });
const model = models[models.length - 1];
this.remove(model);
```

Comment: You can use [findWhere](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-findWhere) to get the model and then pass that in to [remove](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-remove)

Comment: @Jack Sure, but is that necessarily going to respect what pop does with removing the last one?

Comment: pop [delegates](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L910) to remove, just for the last element.

Comment: Being that you want to get the last element that matches you would probably be better off using `where` and then using the last element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pop really just gets the last element and then calls remove on the result, from the [backbone source](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L910)

```
  pop: function(options) {
      var model = this.at(this.length - 1);
      this.remove(model, options);
      return model;
    },
```

Since that's the case you can just use [where](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where) to get the models that match your filter and then pass the last model from the results into [remove](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-remove) yourself.

```
var matchingModels = this.where({type: 'foo'});
this.remove(matchingModels[matchingModels.length - 1]);
```